# Killer AX1650 driver not working ubuntu 16.04`

Tags: 16.04, wireless, adapter, alienware

I am trying to install ubuntu 16.04 on the new Alienware m15 r3 that comes with an AX1650 wifi adapter. I have followed every step to install ubuntu on an Alienware computer, including disabling secure boot and changing from RAID to AHCI. After installing Ubuntu, I install the Nvidia cards, and everything works fine except the wifi. So I followed [this](https://support.killernetworking.com/knowledge-base/killer-ax1650-in-debian-ubuntu-16-04/), which ends up allowing me to connect to wifi networks, however, when I try to connect to a network, the computer freezes, anyone has any idea why is that?

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use 16.04? To explain... From your link, it suggests that things will be easier with a newer kernel than the one that comes with 16.04. The current/newest LTS has a newer kernel and *may* make things go smoother for you. The kernel you're using very likely existed *years* before your newer hardware came into existence.

Comment: I need to use ROS Kinetic for a project I am working on, and it is only compatible with Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: If, and I mean this as a last resort, you can't get it to work (as in nobody helps you), you can add a new PPA and use a newer kernel from [Mainline](https://github.com/bkw777/mainline). Mainline is usually painless and doesn't add bugs nor make your system unstable. If used as directed, it normally works just fine. I highly encourage you to backup your important files, just to be on the safe side. First, wait and see if someone else can help you. You can edit your post and add the results from `uname -a` in the terminal.